# MySQL57Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead

Tags: java, spring-boot

In my Java Spring Boot project I try to migrate User entity into mysql database.

When I mvn spring-boot:run, I see following error:

```
HHH90000026: MySQL57Dialect has been deprecated; use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect instead
```

Here's my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true 
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database=mysql
```

Here's the dependency for mysql:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8.
need to use this dialect and please add in application.properties.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

Comment: Thanks. Now it says: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8

Comment: as per error it says use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect , please try this one.
I am not sure which version of hibernate are you using

Comment: I guess you're using Spring Boot 3, right? It sounds like Spring Data JPA wasn't changed to account for changes in Hibernate 6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the help of Raushan Kumar I solved the connection problem with:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```